Why intersection observer doesnot work through wp code plugin on wordpress
My intersection observer does not work.
I tried to create CSS and javascript code through a wp code plugin on wordpress to create a fadein effect on my elements with the class fade-in when someone scrolls down. But unfortunately, the javascript code didn't work. However, my CSS worked. So I added console log in my javascript code to see what happened and the intersection observer's console log message was missing in the console. Why is my intersection observer not working? This is the javascript code:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    console.log('Script loaded.'); 

    const faders = document.querySelectorAll('.fade-in');
    console.log('Selected elements with class .fade-in:', faders);

    const appearOptions = {
        threshold: 0.5,
    };

    const appearOnScroll = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, appearOnScroll) {
        console.log('IntersectionObserver callback triggered.'); 
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
                return;
            } else {
                entry.target.classList.add("appear");
                console.log('Added class .appear to element:', entry.target); 
                appearOnScroll.unobserve(entry.target);
            }
        });
    }, appearOptions);

    faders.forEach(fader => {
        appearOnScroll.observe(fader);
        console.log('Observing element for intersection:', fader); 
    });
});

